Azure Data Factory: How to retain the file name in the sink through a copy activity
I'm trying to copy a file from SFTP to Blob Storage container. However, after the activity the filename in the Storage container seems completely random and different from that of the source file. How can I persist the file name?
I tried to follow this similar post , but in my case, i dont see the option of 'Dataset Properties' at all, neither for sink nor for source.
What am i missing?



Can you show the Dataset configuration(s)?

Hi Joel! Sorry. saw your comment too late and by then Rakesh has shared the solution.


but in my case, i dont see the option of 'Dataset Properties' at all, neither for sink nor for source

The dataset properties mean the dataset parameters. To see those, first you need to create dataset parameters in both source and sink datasets. As you want your file name to be dynamic, you need to give those parameters in the file name section of the datasets.
Create string type parameter without any default value like below.
Source dataset:

Now, give this in the dataset file name as @dataset().<parameter_name>. Give your source folder path.

To get the child file names from the source folder using Get meta data activity, the dataset path should be only till that folder. So, you cannot use the above dataset for your Get meta data activity as it has dynamic file path.
Create another dataset with path till your source folder and give that to your Get meta data activity at first.
Similarly, do the same for the sink dataset as well. Here, the parameter name is target_filename.

Now, the dataset properties will get appear for both source and sink in copy activity. Give the file name @item().name to these parameters.

In your sink, you have given @item().name expression to copy behavior. Remove it and give the same to the dataset parameter.

Now, the source file(s) will get copied to the target location with same file name.


Thank you, Rakesh. This works and i can have the same name in the sink after copy activity. HOWEVER, when i try to use this file in a data flow as source and look at the data preview, i see all the rows as null. I am trying to copy it to a SQL DB, and this is the error that i get:
"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'D1@#$CRM_Y@#PNMBR', table 'db-@#$-sandbox-dev-001.XX_load_XXX.crmdata_XXX'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
I know this is not exactly related to this question, but do you have any insights?

I cannot say what is the reason by just the error. But, if you are using the dataset parameters for those as well, you need to provide the values for those in the dataflow activity when you debug the pipeline. Or when you hit the data preview, it will ask the parameter values. I think it's better to raise a new question with all the required details and images for the better understanding of the issue.

sure, makes sense.
